# How to execute portion of a code only locally and not on the server

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, build, msbuild

I have a class library and on build I am executing 
`'public override bool Execute()'` method. 
Inside the method I have logic which I want to be performed on build time. 
Inside that method, I also want to start another process while building the library with `'Process.Start("somefile.bat")'`.
My question is - How can I specify that this process should be started when I am trying to build it locally, but not when I am building this on tfs server?

I know that if it was debug vs release I could add `#if debug`, is there something similar to local vs server build?

Answer (score 3):

Try to add `/p:DefineConstants="SERVERBUILD"` to the MSBuild arguments in the "Process" tab of the build definition.
Then you will be able to check with `#if SERVERBUILD` whether the build process is local or on the server.

Comment: I'd just suggest to use a constant for `DEVBUID` and have the server thing be the default just to be sure no one accidentally deploys testing code to production. This can also be set in the `csproj` file in a `<DefineConstants>` property in a matching property group.